# How to make LinearLayout (or any other layout) to stack childs on the right side

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm adding a new views to my LinearLayout on a runtime. I'd like them to be stacked on the right side of the layout.

On the picture clock icon gets stacked on the left, so it's oposite to what I want. Is it possible to make them stack on the right of the higlited LinearLayout? (It can be any other layout, not just Linear if it gives what I want)

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just use an `ActionBar`?

Comment: `LinerLayout` doesn't stack(as on e on top of the other) its children. You'll need a `RelativeLayout` or a `FrameLayout` for this.

Comment: Try to set the gravity of the LinearLayout to right, `linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);`

Comment: @Eric because it's not avalible for Android 2.3 which is like 70% of the market. Stupid google.

Comment: @arcastro I don't think this is gonna work

Comment: You can make use of ActionBarSherlock.It is an extension of the support library designed to facilitate the use of the action bar design pattern across all versions of Android with a single API.http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: @Xylian Yup, exactly what android.fryo said. ActionBarSherlock is designed to work down to Android 2.0, and uses the Android support library v4.

Comment: I know there are libraries for that. I just wanted to make my own one. but thanks @android.fryo

Comment: Try to set layout gravity as right for the linear layout and check it up. It should work I guess

Comment: it doesn't @android.fryo ;)

Comment: Post your code. It will help others to find out the issue easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The blue line is the linear layout selected:

[image: The blue line is the linear layout selected]